# Idiomatic Javascript dependency graph

Tags: javascript, oop, dependency-injection

Given the following Javascript, would it be better/more idiomatic to inject the `MyService` object into `myMethod` so that a fake version of `MyService` could be injected for testing? Or am I missing something?

```
var myObject = {
  myMethod: function() {
    var myService = new MyService();
    return myService.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency injection always takes precedence over hard-coding the dependencies. Also, by coding to interfaces (assuming the myObject instance has been given a copy of a Service object that has a `doSomething()` method) could come handy here.

Comment: By "interface" I presume you mean that the prototype of `MyService` is set to `Service`? Given that methods can be changed dynamically in JS, what are the benefits of this approach over and above simply re-defining (say) `doSomething` in my test?

Comment: Exactly. It has no performance gains. It only makes your program more readable by allowing the reader to understand the contract (interface) and then follow the logic inside the implementation.

Comment: No problem. I hope I've been able to help you.